# What is the difference between these two pools in Uniswap?

Tags: uniswap

I found the strange pools in Uniswap (for me).

They appear to be liquidity pools for each of the same currencies.
I have two questions there.

(1) I thought there was one currency pair liquidity, but is there more than one?

(2) If first question is Yes,When swapped from the UI,Is it random which liquidity pool is used?

【Uniswap V3: USDC 2】0x8ad599c3a0ff1de082011efddc58f1908eb6e6d8

【Uniswap V3: USDC 3】0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pools have different fee tiers, the first one has 0.05% fee, the other one: 0.3% fee.

It is not possible to control which pool is used when swapping from the UI, but it's not random. The pool or the combinations of pools that are most profitable for the swap will be used.